# Render all geometries in an array from geometry generator / QGIS expression editor

Tags: qgis, expression, geometry-generator

I have a line layer and want to add a series of 10 single sided buffers with increasing distance: 1, 2, 3... to 10. With geometry generator, I created this valid expression:

```
array_foreach(
   generate_series(1,10,1),
   single_sided_buffer( 
      $geometry,@element)
)
```

The output of this is an array of geometries. I can get the geometry with `array_get( array,index)`, but like this it's only possible to render one geometry. However, I would like to display all 10 buffers, thus collect all ten geometries contained in the array. How is this possible with expressions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about [`collect_geometries()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/expression.html#geometry-functions)?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

`Geometry Generator` is great for building new geometrie(s) for each initial feature. That is, a main limitation is the inability to produce new row of data.

While it is possible to create a complex multi-polygon geometry, as shown by [@Kazuikito](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/379953/84870), it remains a single geometry with a single style.

If you need control over the generated data, say to label the buffers or use a different color per ring, you would have to prepare the buffers before styling them. This can still be an automatic solution if implemented as a `virtual layer`.

Go the the menu `layer / add layer / add-edit virtual layer` and enter the following query. Feel free to add any field you wish from your layer (here only the id is included)

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE generate_series(value) AS (
  SELECT 1 -- Smallest value
  UNION ALL
  SELECT value+1 FROM generate_series   -- "+1" is the step
   WHERE value+1 <= 10  -- "+1" is the step, 10 is the greatest value
)
SELECT s.value as bufferSize, SingleSidedBuffer(a.geometry, s.value,1) as geometry, a.id
FROM generate_series s, 
     myLineLayer a;
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect idea using the [`SingleSidedBuffer()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#single-sided-buffer). Do you know since when QGIS possess this function for Virtual Layers?

Comment: I was aware of the possibility to do it as a virtual layer, but felt more comfortable to it with geometry generator as I am more familiar with that. For this reason it's really great you added the virtual layer solution, I should really get more familiar with it. To this end, if you could please elaborate about the difference between the code in your answer and the one on your screenshot - there is missing the "as geometry, a.id" part. So with this part included, the query in the virtual layer does not work, whereas when I paste it as in your screenshot, it works.

Comment: @babel it should work if there is an `id` field in the source layer, you can really add any field you need from the source. The `.. as geometry` just gives a nice name to the geometry column, it would work with or without it

Comment: @Taras it is a [spatialite](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-5.0.0.html) function in this case. I don't know when it was introduced

Comment: @JGH, great - yes, adding an id field does the job!